# Spring boot starter data jpa does not respect @BatchSize. Or how to solve/mitigate N+1 issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

=================================================================

Source code of this question can be found [HERE](https://github.com/anaconda875/product/tree/n-plus-1)

Spring boot version: 2.7.16

Mariadb version: 10.7.8

=================================================================

I'm develop a simple app. I have an entity named Category that have self reference to itself (list of child):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_category")
@Data
@NamedEntityGraph(
  name = "test",
  attributeNodes = {
    @NamedAttributeNode(value="children",subgraph="children"),
  },
  subgraphs = {
    @NamedSubgraph(
      name = "children",
      attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("children")
      }
    )
  })
@BatchSize(size = 10)
public class Category {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Basic(optional = false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne
  @ToString.Exclude
  private Category parent;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
  @ToString.Exclude
  @BatchSize(size = 10)
  private List<Category> children;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
  @ToString.Exclude
  private List<Product> products;

}
```

I want to load a Category by id (and its children of type Category too) without N+1 issue.
I searched on Google and found this [article](https://jivimberg.io/blog/2018/08/04/recursive-queries-on-rdbms-with-jpa/).

My first try is about using entity graph. But entity graph only work in case a Category have at most two hierarchy: the current parent and its children. More than two hierarchy, N+1 shown up.

So I switched to second solution: `JOIN FETCH`

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {

  //@EntityGraph(value = "test", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  @Query("SELECT DISTINCT c FROM Category c JOIN FETCH c.children")
  Optional<Category> findById(Long id);

}
```

But it does not work. I got this exception: `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 3`

So I applied the last solution: `@BatchSize(size = 10)`, but no luck, N+1 still shown up

Below is some related code snipe:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DefaultCategoryService implements CategoryService {

  private final CategoryRepository repository;

  @Override
  public CategoryResponse save(CategoryRequest request) {
    Category entity = toEntity(request);
    entity = repository.save(entity);

    return new CategoryResponse(entity);
  }

  @Override
  public CategoryResponse findById(Long id) {
    return repository.findById(id).map(this::toResponse)
      .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException(String.format("Category with id [%d] is not found", id)));
  }

  private CategoryResponse toResponse(Category category) {
    return new CategoryResponse(category);
  }

  private Category toEntity(CategoryRequest request) {
    Category entity = new Category();
    entity.setName(request.getName());
    List<Category> children = Optional.ofNullable(request.getChildren())
      .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
      .stream()
      .map(cr -> {
        Category child = toEntity(cr);
        child.setParent(entity);

        return child;
      })
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    entity.setChildren(children);


    return entity;
  }

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryResponse {

  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private List<CategoryResponse> children;

  public CategoryResponse(Category entity) {
    this.id = entity.getId();
    this.name = entity.getName();
    this.children = Optional.ofNullable(entity.getChildren())
      .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
      .stream()
      .map(CategoryResponse::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
}

@Data
public class CategoryRequest {

  private String name;
  private List<CategoryRequest> children;

}
```

This is request to create Category with hierarchy:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/categories' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "3",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'
```

Please help!! Why spring boot does not respect my @BatchSize? Or, how to solve/mitigate N+1 issue?

Comment: Actually you need to write a recursive query to fetch it in one query. Maybe you can investigate it from google. Native query can be mandatory in case of writing recursive query. Also you can simply get root and fetch it one call. For example you have parent entity then you changed fetch type to Eager then you can simply get all of them.

If you need a specific count or size, I prefer to write recursive query with limiting a fetch size. Maybe there can be more effective solutions but I don't know.